# Why is HttpPost using a GET method? [Android]

Tags: android

I am executing the following post in Android:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.example.com");  
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("account", "login"));  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "email@email.com));  
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));  
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

In the server side I return the cgi.request_method variable and it is GET.
Shouldn't it be POST? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

That code should initiate a POST, not a GET. I would guess that something on the server side is misconfigured.

Comment: What kind of misconfiguration can it be? I am using ColdFusion and it serves up pages and processes form posts properly on websites.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about ColdFusion.

Answer (score -1):

My problem was send http instead of https